# How to write a regex correctly?

Tags: regex, regex-group

My goal is to find entries in the text that have the form

1. [{XX} xxx]
2. [ xxx {XX} xxx]
3. [xxx {XX}]

(with parentheses inclusive)
xxx is a random value

I tried to do and this is what happened to do

```
\[*(?=\{.*\}]*)([^]]+)\]
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work 100% right

blocked for [{XX} xxxx] [{XX xxx] [10 xxx] [xxx{XXX} xx] {X} io]
[image]

I wanted to see 2 options highlighted: [{XX} xxxx] and [xxx{SSS} xx]

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following regex:

```
\[[^\[]*?\s?{[^{]+}\s?[^\]]*?\]
```

Regex Explanation:

- `\[`: open bracket
- `[^\[]*?`: least amount of non-open bracket characters
- `\s?`: optional space
- `{[^{]+}`: least amount of non-open braces between braces
- `\s?`: optional space
- `[^\]]*?`: least amount of non-closed bracket characters
- `\]`: closed bracket

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/KppwKn/1).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but there's a problem. If you remove one or another curly brace, this will lead to the capture of extra text

Comment: Make an example with the fiddle at the bottom of this answer, including what should (or should not) be matched.